# Web page printing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML on my webpage:

```
<div id=header>
   <a href="/" id="logo" name="logo"><span class="hide">FooBar</span></a>
      <div id="topnavmenu">
         <ul id="nav-utility">
            <li><a href="/careers">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="/test4/">Test4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/program">Program</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

When I print the page, I get:

```
(/)   Careers (/careers)   Blog(/blog)   Test4(/test4) ....
```

Problems:

1. Logo image not displayed. Works ok on screen
2. Why am I getting the href printed in parents? How do I suppress this?

This is using bootstrap, but I'm not sure if bootstrap is the culprit.

Thanks,

P

Answer (score 2):

Things to remember while writing print css :-

1. We dont need navigation to browse on paper - So hide navigation from printing.
2. Remove banners,ads any unwanted images .
3. Font size should be scaled to a good number which is visible to eyes and not very big.
4. Dont Print background images. Keep it white.

You will have to use CSS Media Styles to provide specifics to print out certain areas.Good practice will be to use a separate stylesheet containing all the print css like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Than write your css styles inside the print.css like the following

```
@media print {
/* your stylesheet for printing, eg.: */
   body {
           color : #000000;
           background : #ffffff;
           font-family :"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
           font-size : 12pt;
        }
  a {
           text-decoration : underline;
           color : #ddd;
    }
 #topnavmenu {
          display : none;
    }
   #logo {
       height:20px;
       margin-top:10px;

    }
}
```

Bootstrap css is not the culprit,since its specified with media="screen" attribute which is why it will only affect the screens not the print .

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

The other way would be to assign `MEDIA="screen, print"` to the bootstrap file. **But thats only advisable** if you want to print your website exactly the way it appears on desktop . "So Save Trees " and print only those areas which are absolutely necessary .
Example for assigning media="screen,print" to the bootstrap css:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,print">
```

Answer (score 2):

### How to suppress href from parents in printed version.

Those hrefs are feature of Bootstrap. If you look at Bootstrap CSS you'll find this:

```
a[href]:after{
    content:" (" attr(href) ")"
}

abbr[title]:after{
    content:" (" attr(title) ")"
}
```

This is the problem. You can delete it if you have access to Bootstrap. Otherwise just suppress it it your own CSS:

```
a[href]:after{
    content:"";
}

abbr[title]:after{
    content:"";
}
```

You can even add `!important` to each line.

```
a[href]:after{
    content:"" !important;
}

abbr[title]:after{
    content:"" !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Backgrounds images typically aren't printed.
2. You can't with code. You have to adjust this in the print options dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions above, remember that if print results are important to you, then that's what the print stylesheet is for.

Include a reference to the stylesheet in the head of your doc:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

then style this as you wish.

For example if you want to hide the menu when printing the page include something like this:

```
#topnavmenu{
display:none;
}
```

Here's one good link to get you started on styling your print stylesheet:
http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint

Hope this helps!